# Building slider with Low Variables, Matrix and playa

Tags: matrix, playa, low-variables, channel-images

I am not figuring this one out. It's my first time trying to combine Low Variables, Matrix, and playa.

I have a slider on the homepage that is populated with Low Variables. Within LV I used Matrix to create the individual slides.

Within Matrix you can choose a project with playa which pulls in the background image (channel images), the title, and location with a link to the project.

There is another field in Matrix to give a general title to the slide. Below is my code, any help would be great!

```
<div class="flexslider masthead">
<ul class="slides">
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_home_slider"}
{lv_home_slider}
<li>
<div class="inside-wrap">
<div class="masthead-txt">
<h1>{hero-tagline}</h1>
{exp:playa:children var="featured_project" limit="1"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
<h4>{project-location}</h4>
<a href="{title_permalink='what-we-do/projects'}" class="btn btn-fill">View Details</a>
</div>
</div>          
{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" field="masthead_image" limit="1"}
<div data-picture data-alt="{title}">
<div data-src="{image:url:small}"></div>
<div data-src="{image:url:medium}" data-media="(min-width: 700px)"></div>
<div data-src="{image:url}" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></div>
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<div data-src="{image:url}"></div>
<![endif]-->
<noscript>
<img src="{image:url}" alt="{title}">
</noscript>
</div>
{/exp:channel_images:images}
{/exp:playa:children}
</li>
{/lv_home_slider}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
</ul>
</div><!--flexslider-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Low Variables point of view, you don't need to add the Matrix variable pair inside the `low_variables:pair` tags. So instead of this:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="my_matrix_var"}
    {my_matrix_var}
         matrix content here
    {/my_matrix_var}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

...you'd need to use this:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="my_matrix_var"}
     matrix content here
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

As for all the Matrix/Playa/Channel Images bits; can't really help with that, although it would be useful for you to add what it is that's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks Low, I must have needed some time away from it. With your comment I took out the Matrix variable pair, but realized I wasn't including the matrix tag wrap around the playa content. That did the trick!